# Real Analysis: Cauchy, continuous sequence examples

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

a continuous function $f: (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ and a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ such that $f(x_n)$ is not a Cauchy sequence.

a continuous function $f: [0,1] \to\mathbb{R}$ and a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ such that $f(x_n)$ is not a Cauchy sequence

a continuous function $f: [0,\infty ) \to\mathbb{R}$ and a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ such that $f(x_n)$ is not a Cauchy sequence

Examples for all of the above?
Could anyone please help?

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know about uniformly continuous functions and how they treat cauchy sequences?

Comment: Just think of f(x)=1/xforx∈(0,1)and x_n =1/n for n∈N. f(x_n) =n. Does it work? For question 2 and 3 my example will fail because it is undefined at 0. Are those two possibles have a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You are correct for the first example.
2. It is not possible, because if $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then it is uniformly continuous. Suppose $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, and $\epsilon > 0$, there is $\delta > 0$ such that
   $$
   |x-y| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(y)| <\epsilon \quad\forall x,y\in [0,1]
   $$
   For this $\delta > 0, \exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
   $$
   |x_n - x_m| < \delta \quad\forall n,m \geq N
   $$
   and so conclude that $f(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.
3. Again, this is not possible, because if $(x_n)$ is Cauchy in $[0,\infty)$, then it converges in $\mathbb{R}$, since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete. Since $[0,\infty)$ is closed, there is a point $x \in [0,\infty)$ such that $x_n \to x$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ and so $f(x_n)$ must be a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal : Could you give an example/explain why my explanation is wrong? Maybe I am missing something, but a Cauchy sequence is bounded, so the function is effectively uniformly continuous on the (large enough) closed interval containing the sequence, right?

Comment: for (3) you need the function to be uniformly continuous.

Comment: if $(x_n)$ is cauchy in $[0,\infty)$ then shouldn't it be case that it converges in $[0,\infty)$ too(coverges in $\mathbb{R}$ is too weak statement) By order limit theorem?